# (Java downcasting) What did I do wrong in this example?

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, polymorphism

I try to downcast in this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Animal a = new Animal();
    ((Cat)a).makePee();
}
```

`Cat` extends `Animal` and both have the same Method `makePee()`.
If I try to run this, The compiler shows me an error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Animal cannot be cast to Cat
>       at Main.main(Main.java:6)

But in the Example of the App Lern Java is shown really the same as I do.

Comment: This is a very well written question, but "Example of the App Lern Java is shown really the same as I do" simply can't be true.

Answer (score 6):

Well, `a` isn't an instance of a `Cat`. If you want to downcast it to a `Cat`, you need to actually create a `Cat` (or an instance of some class that extends `Cat`, of course):

```
Animal a = new Cat();
```

Note, however, that if `Animal` declares `makePee()` and `Cat` overrides it, the downcasting is pointless. You can just call `a.makePee()`, and `Cat`'s implementation would be used (provided you actually created a `Cat`, as noted above).